# Getting user input in one function of the class and using it in another in Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to create a class in Python, having two functions "Dataset" and "LoadImages". Here is the code:

```
class GUI:
  def __init__(self):
    self.File=[];

  def Dataset(self):
    self.File = askdirectory(initialdir="D:/",title='Load the dataset.')
    return self.File

  def LoadImages(self):
    print self.File
    paths = []
    for fname in os.listdir(self.File):
        if fname.split(".")[-1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
            paths.append(os.path.join(self.File, fname))
```

I want the user to input a directory in "Dataset" and then save it in `self.File`, and now I want the function "LoadImages" to read the image files in the path `self.File` specified by the user. 
I am first calling `GUI().Dataset`, that will get an input directory from the user, and then  `GUI().LoadImages` to get read the images in a directory. But the second time I call `GUI().LoadImages`,the class is again initialized and `self.File` is set to `[]`. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly...

When you call `GUI()` you are instantiating the class.  If you want to make a second call to the same  GUI instance you need to assign it to a variable like this:

```
my_gui = GUI()
my_gui.Dataset()
my_gui.LoadImages()
```

There are many other stylistic issues with your code, and i did not even look at the contents of the methods.  Most importantly, only class names should be capitalized, method and variable names should be lowercase. With that being said, the above code should answer your question.